# Showing index.htm and index.php both

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

I have a static HTML based site.

Server automatically pulls the `index.htm` as the default page. Fine.

I just installed WordPress in the root:
But `.com/index.php` is redirecting automatically to `.com/index.htm`.

I need to be able to see both `index.htm` (as main page for current site visitors) and `index.php` for my work on the theme and new WordPress pages.

Also, when I do the *.htaccess*: `DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm`.

I am then able to see the WordPress `.com/index.php` but then can no longer see `index.htm` as the site then defaults to the `index.php`.

How can I see both `index.htm` and `index.php` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This normally simply works out of the box by *not* having a `RewriteRule` or `DirectoryIndex` for the root of either site. If it does not for you, you will have to provide the contents of your *.htaccess*.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I thought, but when I opened the htaccess file it was blank... Meaning, the default was a blank htaccess file.

Comment: It works that way *here* on my own server. Would this be on shared hosting? There is most likely a default .htaccess file somewhere else and settings are inherited. Look at parent directories if they are accessible to you. On some service provides, you have a control panel interface which lets you change similar settings.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your current static page in the home.php file of your WP theme? This way it will be shown when somebody types yourdomain.com. At the same time, you can continue working on your WP theme. If you need a separate home page layout for your WP theme, you can create a page in WP (say, "Home") responsible for your WP home page, create a template file for it and test it under, say, yourdomain.com/home